# Prevent double withdrawal ERC20 API attack

Tags: solidity, security, erc-20

How do I prevent against the double withdrawal attack described in [ERC20 API: An Attack Vector on Approve/TransferFrom Methods](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YLPtQxZu1UAvO9cZ1O2RPXBbT0mooh4DYKjA_jp-RLM/edit#) and [initially posted here](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729)?

An example of the attack:

> 1. Alice allows Bob to transfer N of Alice's tokens (N>0)  by calling approve method on Token smart contract passing Bob's address and N as method arguments
> 2. After some time, Alice decides to change from N to M (M>0) the number of Alice's tokens Bob is allowed to transfer, so she calls approve method again, this time passing Bob's address and M as method arguments
> 3. Bob notices Alice's second transaction before it was mined and quickly sends another transaction that calls transferFrom method to transfer N Alice's tokens somewhere
> 4. If Bob's transaction will be executed before Alice's transaction, then Bob will successfully transfer N Alice's tokens and will gain an ability to transfer another M tokens
> 5. Before Alice noticed that something went wrong, Bob calls transferFrom method again, this time to transfer M Alice's tokens.
>
> So, Alice's attempt to change Bob's allowance from N to M (N>0 and M>0) made it possible for Bob to transfer N+M of Alice's tokens, while Alice never wanted to allow so many of her tokens to be transferred by Bob.

Answer (score 7):

[EIP20 refers readers to the MiniMeToken implementation](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md#implementation-of-adding-the-force-to-0-before-calling-approve-again) regarding this issue which works around it by [adding the line](https://github.com/Giveth/minime/blob/master/contracts/MiniMeToken.sol#L263):

```
require((_amount == 0) || (allowed[msg.sender][_spender] == 0));
```

EIP20 refers readers to two example token implementations (I've linked to the relevant line numbers):

- [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/StandardToken.sol#L41) - Brief issue description and link to the original issue comment. Mentions "[o]ne possible solution to mitigate this race condition", but doesn't implement it.
- [ConsenSys](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/blob/master/contracts/StandardToken.sol#L47) - no mention or attempt to work around the issue

The [MiniMeToken function comment](https://github.com/Giveth/minime/blob/master/contracts/MiniMeToken.sol#L251) says:

> This is a modified version of the ERC20 approve function to be a little bit safer

Given this is the reference implementation, I would like to be a lot more confident than "a little bit safer".

There is no backward compatible resolution to this problem, and the [solution is still being discussed](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/738).